# c++ Boost asio error: no shared cipher

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, boost-asio

I am currently setting a RESTful API with boost asio.

Connecting from a client works fine via HTTP. But if I try to connect via HTTPS I get an error on the server side: "no shared cipher".
The error seems to come from the openssl implementation, but I have no idea what to make of it. My first guess would be that that no cypher algorithm is set, but I cannot see how this can be done in asio.

This is what I put in the code and where the error occurs:

```
auto acceptHandler = boost::bind(&self::onAccept, this, connection,
                                 boost::asio::placeholders::error);
connection->async_accept(m_acceptor, acceptHandler);

m_sslContext.set_options(
        context::default_workarounds | context::no_sslv2 | context::single_dh_use);
m_sslContext.use_certificate_file(filename, context::pem);
m_sslContext.use_private_key_file(filename, context::pem);
```

Anyone ever had this before or got it working?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and solved it this way.You have to generate a private key and a certificate file for your server. Here is the procedure to do so :

```
// Generate a new ssl private key :
$openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 1024

// Create a certificate signing request using your new key
$openssl req -new -key privkey.pem -out certreq.csr

// Self-sign your CSR with your own private key:
$openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in certreq.csr -signkey privkey.pem -out newcert.pem

// Install the signed certificate and private key for use by an ssl server
// This allows you to use a single file for certificate and private key
$( openssl x509 -in newcert.pem; cat privkey.pem ) > server.pem

// If you use a dh temp file :
$openssl dhparam -outform PEM -out dh512.pem 512
```

Then, copy the `server.pem` and `dh512.pem` files in your server execution directory.

If you use the tmp dh file you also have to add this line of code `m_sslContext.use_tmp_dh_file("dh512.pem");`

Comment: You should prefer using dh2048 or it may throw an exception "Failed to DH512 - dh key too small"

Answer (score 4):

I got same error when feed unconfigured `boost::asio::ssl::context` object to `boost::asio::ssl::stream` object constructor, which then used as resulted socket of accepting:

```
server()
    : m_acceptor(/*args*/)
    , m_context(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv1_server)
    , m_stream(m_io_service, m_context)
{
    // `m_context` configuring, BUT `m_stream` is unaffected
    m_acceptor.async_accept(m_stream.lowest_layer(), accept_result_handler);
}
// run somewhere `m_io_service.run()`, or other processor of `async` operations.
```

And after actual accept connection and process handshake on it the handshake handler receive `boost::system::error_code` with value 336109761 and message `no shared cipher`.

So first create and configure `boost::asio::ssl::context` and then construct `boost::asio::ssl::stream` with it:

```
typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_type;
typedef boost::asio::ssl::stream<socket_type> stream_type;

std::shared_ptr<stream_type> m_stream;

server()
    : m_acceptor(/*args*/)
    , m_context(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv1_server)
{
    // `m_context` configuring
    m_stream = std::make_shared<stream_type>(m_io_service, m_context);
    m_acceptor.async_accept(m_stream->lowest_layer(), accept_result_handler);
}
```

And don't forget create new stream for each new connection, context can be the same.

Answer (score 2):

As @asiocity points out, the essential part is to **fully configure** the ssl::context **before** initialising the ssl::stream.

It is hard to initialise them both in an initialiser list while still deferring the ssl::stream until the ssl::context is fully configured.

One way I use is to subclass the ssl::context and override the constructor so that it can be fully configured in the initializer list, before the ssl::stream is initialised.

e.g.

```
class server_context : public boost::asio::ssl::context {
  public: server_context(boost::asio::ssl::context::method m, std::string certfile);
};
```

...

```
server_context::server_context(boost::asio::ssl::context::method m, std::string certfile)
: boost::asio::ssl::context(m)
{
  use_private_key_file(certfile);
  use_certificate_chain_file(certfile);
}
```

...

```
class myclass {
  private:
    server_context : ssl_context_;
    boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&> stream_;
  public:
    myclass(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&, std::string certfile);
```

...

```
myclass::myclass(std::string certfile) 
: ssl_context_(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23, certfile),
  stream_(socket, ssl_context_) 
{
  ...
}
```

However that seems a lot of work to avoid a shared_ptr

I'm wishing/hoping for some constructor-mixin/template trick that would allow me to do this with just a custom initializer list rather than a subclass.