# Boost ASIO library - SSL - No shared cipher

Tags: c++, windows, ssl, boost-asio

I have problems to get SSL working with asio library.

this is how i set up a server part.

```
serverServicePtr->network_context->set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds| boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 );
serverServicePtr->network_context->set_password_callback(boost::bind(&ServerService::GetPassword));
serverServicePtr->network_context->use_private_key_file("privkey.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
...
clientSocket->handshake( boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::server );
```

client part:

```
boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
ctx.load_verify_file("pubkey.pem");

ctx.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
ctx.set_verify_callback(boost::bind(&verify_certificate, _1, _2));  

boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> s(io_service, ctx);
boost::asio::connect(s.lowest_layer(), iterator);
s.lowest_layer().set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true));  
s.handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client);
```

it failes on handshake. Server says "handshake: no shared cipher" and client just says. that server refuses client.

My question is, where is a problem? What i am missing? perhaps, i generated my keys wrong? How to generate them right for asio?

Comment: Could this be of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217346/c-boost-asio-error-no-shared-cipher

Comment: i've tested it actually .. and i got error "handshake: short read" :)

Comment: at least it's a different error now, some progress. :)

Comment: i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452756/exception-running-boost-asio-ssl-example and it helps me :) it was a certificate problem. That was luck i found that as there is no "no shared cipher" problem

Comment: How did you generate your public and private keys?