# handshake: unsupported protocol (SSL routines) [asio.ssl:167772418] | [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:997)

Tags: python, c++, tls1.3

I'm trying to write a simpel client-server application with **tlsv1.3**.

The client is in Python and the server is in C++.
In Python documentation i saw that Python only support **tlsv1.3**.

So in my server I've set the tls version to 1.3.
In the title the firs error is from VS (C++) and the second one is from Python.

I'm attaching both scripts and I will really aprichate any help I can get. Thank you for your help !

**server:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#define PORT 8080
#define MAX_LEN 1024

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;

void main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ctx;
    std::thread ctx_thread{ [&ctx]() { ctx.run(); } };

    ssl::context ssl_ctx(ssl::context::tlsv13_server);
    ssl_ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::context::verify_none);

    tcp::acceptor a(ctx, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), PORT));

    std::cout << "waiting for connection..." << std::endl;
    auto socket = a.accept(); // this waits for client to open session
    ssl::stream<decltype(socket)> ssl_stream(std::move(socket), ssl_ctx);
    try {
        ssl_stream.handshake(ssl::stream_base::server);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }

    std::cout << "connection establish" << std::endl;
    //char data[MAX_LEN];

    if (ctx_thread.joinable())
        ctx_thread.join();
}
```

**client:**

```
import socket
import ssl
import sys

HOST, PORT = '127.0.0.1', '8080'


# send message to the server, check if the message sent
def send_to_server(channel, message):
    try:
        channel.sendall(str.encode(message))
    except socket.error:
        print("can't send on this channel")
        sys.exit(1)


# receive a message from the server, check if the message received
def receive_from_server(channel):
    try:
        return channel.recv(2048)
    except socket.error as e:
        print("can't receive on this channel")
        print(str(e))
        sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    context.set_ciphers('DEFAULT')
    with socket.create_connection((HOST, PORT)) as sock:
        try:
            with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=HOST) as ssock:
                print(ssock.version())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

I've expected client-server application with tls version 1.3,
I got nothing.

Comment: **i saw that Python only support tlsv1.3** vs. **tlsv1 alert protocol version**. Don't you see the conflict?

Comment: if i see the conflict i wouldn't ask, don't you think ?

Comment: I've tried different versions of tls,ssl nothing is working

Comment: Your C++ server is throwing "handshake: no shared cipher (SSL routines) [asio.ssl:167772353]". Have you tried the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217346/c-boost-asio-error-no-shared-cipher)?